# Android Custom Listview issue - for time schedule can I change the text color and size?

Tags: android, listview, customization

I'm working on a project which is something like bus schedule.And I'm curious about one thing : Is there any way to do something like this :

[image: listview] This is how I want to look like my list view. My idea is to get the current time and than show when the first bus depending on current time is leaving. So if it's `12:00 am/pm` I want to show that the next bus is leaving at 12:15 like this.To make the text in different color and make it bigger.

Any ideas or suggestions how can I do that or is it possible to make something like that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using list selector? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to filter the list view,but it's not working as I want..I need to be able to show the past times too.I've tried getPosition(int), but this didn't help either.That's why I am asking this question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use custom adapter for listview and from that class's getview() method just check your current time from that get the depend time. If It available then change the text and font of that list row (textview) simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the required item as selected item. Then in `onItemSelected` listener you can change its text color and size. Also maintain the current selected item in a member so that you can revert the size and color when it's unselected.

Reference :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html